# Threads not Garbage collected / ThreadPool threads / C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net

In my C#/.NET 3.5 program I am using Threadpool threads ( delegate+BeginInvoke/EndInvoke) to parallelize and speed up some file loading. SystemInternals tool ProcessExplorer shows that number of threads in process is increasing over time, while I would expect to stay the same. Looks like some Threads/Threads handles stay hanging around for no reason.

Interestingly enough, I can not find pattern how threads grow and seems that happen sporadically, without repeatable pattern each time I start application. I spend some time analyzing and here are some observations:

1) code looks like this:

```
ArrayList IAsyncResult_s = new ArrayList();
   AsyncProcessing thread1 = processRasterLayer;
... ArrayList filesToRender....
 foreach (string FileName in filesToRender)
    {
      string fileName2 = FileName;
      GeoImage partialImage1;
      IAsyncResult asyncResult = thread1.BeginInvoke(
                                fileName2, .....,
                                out partialImage1, ..., null, null);
      IAsyncResult_s.Add(asyncResult);
      asyncResult = null;
    }
.................
//block and render all
foreach (IAsyncResult asyncResult in IAsyncResult_s)
{
  GeoImage partialImage1;
  thread1.EndInvoke(
  out partialImage1,   , asyncResult);
  //render image.. some calls to render partial image here
  partialImage1.Dispose();
  partialImage1 = null;
}
IAsyncResult_s.Clear();
IAsyncResult_s = null;
thread1 = null;
```

---

2) Number of Process Threads
My trace shows that during execution inside loop, `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);` gives numbers like 493, 1000.
At the end of loops , , `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);` gives numbers 500, 1000. So, number of available thread returns to same
Number of process threads reported by `SystemInternals ProcessExplorer` and API `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()`.Threads.Count is the 16 before loops, and around 21 after loops. 
If I call againg those loops, number of threads in process grows, but not by fixed nubmer each time, but grows 1-4 each time I repeat above code, so grows like 16->21->22->26->31...

3)Forced garbage collection didn’t htelp
I tried to froce garbage collection to get rid of those extra threads, but that didn’t removed them from process.

4)Profling tools
I was using RedGates Memory and Performace profilers, but hasen’t  found obvious reason. I saw several extra threas and their object (ThreadContext etc) hanging, but saw no object holding those threads in memory. I am prety sure those extra threads were involved into loops work above, since I added thread name inside calls, and they still have that name I gave them.

5) Intelitrace
Intelitrace debuging showed also extra threads hanging. They still have names I gave them. But interestingly, it also showed that same thread that is hanging now, was used by above loop in the past, but also same thread was executing some timer related evens from timers form my code.

6) Locating issue
So, When I disable above loops that process filse Asynchroniously, and load files sequentialy, I do not have extra threads, and number of threads in my application is constant and and around 16.

7) Regarding SetMaxThreads :Here how it looks on my machine (XP, .NET 3.5):

Code like this:

ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out AvailableWorkerThreads, out AvailableCompletionPortThreads);
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out MaxWorkerThreads, out MaxCompletionPortThreads);
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out MinWorkerThreads, out MinCompletionPortThreads);

Gives result:

MinWorkerThreads:2  MaxWorkerThreads:500  MinCompletionPortThreads:2  MaxCompletionPortThreads:1000  AvailableWorkerThreads:500  AvailableCompletionPortThreads:1000

My app is using maybe 8 worker threads at the same time. I see no problem with SetMaxThreads.

8)
Functionally, I have no problems so far with this solution above. But somehow, if tools report that number of threads in my app is growing, it looks like “resource leak” of some kind, and I would like to address it. It looks like some thread handles are hanging around for no reason.

9) Here is one interesting article. It sasy that thread resources are cleaned once EndInvoke is called. I am doing so in my code. Article sasy: ..”. Because EndInvoke cleans up after the spawned thread, you must make sure that an EndInvoke is called for each BeginInvoke.”   “If the thread pool thread has exited, EndInvoke does the following: It cleans up the exited thread's loose ends and disposes of its resources.” See: http://en.csharp-online.net/Asynchronous_Programming%E2%80%94BeginInvoke_EndInvoke

10) Another interesting article. Author says he had thread handle leaks because he was creating controls from non-gui thread. It is pretty elaborate article, see: http://msmvps.com/blogs/senthil/archive/2008/05/29/the-case-of-the-leaking-thread-handles.aspx

11) Another interesting article. It talks about ThreadPool.SetMinThreads property. It seems that it is not ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads but ThreadPool.SetMinThreads that enables useful control over ThradPool. This article is an eye-opener for me, and made me think about how ThreadPool works and performance problems it might cause. Article is: http_://www.dotnetperls.com/threadpool-setminthreads . Anoter similar one is : http_://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3813/NET-s-ThreadPool-Class-Behind-The-Scenes

12) Another interesting article. It is talking about throttling issue with ThreadPool. Article mentions ThreadPool limit of 2 new threads per second increase. See http_://social. msdn. microsoft. com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/3325cb32-371b-4f3e-965f-6ca88538dc3e/

13) So, in maybe 30 tests I saw only 2 times that number of threads allocated would shrink. But, it did happen. I saw once thread number going like 16->....->31->61->  ->30->16. So, it went back to 16. It doesn’t happen often, and it is not about time waited, it was like big activity in process, followed by a period of constant low level activity.

14) ThreadPool.SetMinThreads Method documentation. It talks about 2 new threads per second limit for threadpool. It is not clear if setting this property would remove that limit. http_://msdn.microsoft. com/en-ca/library/system. threading.threadpool.setminthreads(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Are you managing large objects on each thread?

Comment: What problem is this presenting?

Comment: I may be wrong.. but AFAIK `Thread` is not something managed by GC. Threads are managed by the ThreadPool. When you put more and more work to it, ThreadPool creates more threads. And as the work load gets lower, it decides whether to release some threads , or still keep them around for any more work you might throw at it in the future. I'd say you give .NET some time (let's say 5-7 minutes) after your work load is done, and then count the threads again. By that time, if you (any other library you use) didn't schedule more work, .NET would decide to let those threads go. But I may be wrong.

Comment: You've described -- mostly correctly -- how .NET manages pooled threads. You haven't actually asked a question. **Is there a question you'd like to get an answer to?**  ("Mostly" because you have at least one false statement in there: that the threads hang around "for no reason". They hang around for a very good reason: they're pooled.)

Comment: Well, what I claim is that once all work by ThreadPool threads is done ( i.e. EndInvoke is called for all work threads), I see increase of threads in process from 16 to 21 and up to 42 etc. I believe that is a resource leak and the question is how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

So the answer is: there's no leak here. This is how the thread pool works. It keeps around threads that finished working so you don't have to pay the price of thread creation next time you need one. If you have many concurrent work items then the number of threads in the pool will increase but they'll max out at MaxWorkerThreads. (And it has nothing to do with the garbage collector.)

See this article for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx

Comment: I do not understand why would it “keep threads” inside my application process. And if I pool maybe 6-12 parallel threads, and after they FINISH I get 1-4 extra threads in my process EACH TIME. Number of threads is growing from 16.. up to 41.

Answer (score 0):

i would consider a consumer producer pattern. the idea behind a threadpool is to recycle threads, not create hundreds of new. in best case you have for each cpu one thread, and queue the work. this will be sure faster as you avoid useless context switches and waits for creating new threads, as far as i remember the net threadpool waits about one second until a new thread is created, to give other threads a chance to get recycled.

Comment: additional point, you use async code which adds also threads for callbacks.